# programmatically check git for new versions if then pull

Tags: git, github, server, pull

I have a digitalocean droplet running nginx to serve my html files and redirecting urls to a backend with a rest-api.

When I want to update the frontend or backend on the server, I have this tedious process of ssh'ing into it, pulling either backend or frontend, if frontend then build and restarting services. I am looking for a way to somehow automatize some steps or all of it. Is there any technologies that could help?

Comment: As @NewEyes suggested in their (deleted) answer, this is the sort of thing you could automate with a simple shell script and standard tools like `cron` (which can run a script at a specified interval). We're not going to write it for you, but if you try yourself and run into problems we can probably help out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hook+push+to+deploy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write cron script where you can check if origin branch HEAD is different form local branch HEAD:

```
# check remote head
git ls-remote origin refs/heads/your_branch

#check local head
git rev-parse HEAD

# if remote HEAD is different than local HEAD, then pull
```

This solution is for one branch only (for exapmle `your_branch` is `master`). If you want i can write for you complete script which will check if all your local branches is synchronised with remote branches.
I would like that script in python, but bash is also an option.

BTW

In my opinion auto pull is not a good solution. What if you have uncommited changes? Stash them, and after pulling apply?
What if you have unpublished commit? Are you should do just pure pull or pull with rebase?
With fetching you do not have this kind problems :)
Auto fetching is much better option in my opinion, and if you want just merge changes with your git working directory.
If you consider fetching instead pull (`pull` is `fetch` and `merge`) then locally you should check `FETCH_HEAD`, but please take into account that `FETCH_HEAD` is temp.

The other issue is that if your repository have submodules.